# Как вызвать у объекта добавленного в коллекцию, метод многопоточности start()?

Tags: java, многопоточность, коллекции, arraylist

Есть коллекция ArrayList с объектами класса реализующего интерфейс Runnable() для многопоточности. Как вызвать у объекта добавленного в коллекцию, метод start() ?

Answer (score 1):

Классы, реализующие интерфейс `Runnable` должны реализовать метод `void run()`. При вызове этого метода код закономерно выполняется в потоке, вызвавшем этот метод.

```
collection.get(n).run();
```

Чтобы запустить выполнение метода `run()` в новом потоке, нужно поместить в конструктор класса `Thread` класс, реализующий интерфейс `Runnable`, а потом вызвать у него(класса `Thread`) метод `start()`:

```
new Thread(collection.get(n)).start();
```

Либо создать наследника класса `Thread`, который будет перезаписывать метод `run()`, а потом вызвать у экземпляра наследника метод `start()`:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Я выполняюсь в новом потоке!");
    }
}
```

и вызов:

```
new MyThread().start();
```

Comment: collection.get(n)).start(); так не работает, метод старт вообще не подсвечивается, только run(). Но если run() запустить то он же не запустится в новом потоке?

Comment: Аа, понял, метод старт нужно вызывать у объекта Thread??а не у объекта из коллекции?

Comment: @Ivan да, метод start запускает новый поток(от класса Thread), в котором выполняется метод run интерфейса Runnable

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то можно так

```
List<Runnable> rList = new ArrayList();
for(Runnable r : rList){
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

Если вы хотите запускать поток в момент добавления элемента в коллекцию, тогда можете реализовать свою коллекцию, которая после добавления в нее объекта будет создавать и запускать поток. Еще более гибкий вариант - ваша коллекция может публиковать событие о добавлении элемента в коллекцию, а создавать и запускать поток будете в слушателе.